# Getting data from another website which is using AJAX to change content

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, simple-html-dom

Is there any way how to get data from another website which is using AJAX to change its content? For now, I am using PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser, but I can't use it in this case. I want to simulate just one click. And after this click, I get new data which I want to parse.

Answer (score 0):

If the website has RSS feeds. Try using that instead. http://website.com/rss.xml or whatever the rss url is. Then you can use Simplepie, or any other RSS Feed parser to get the data.

Comment: Thanks but it has not.